# Complexity is O(log(log(n))) but how can i prove that?

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

I'm new at the topic of complexity analysis and I have a while loop which stars from 3 and goes to n. It grows exponentially anyway but i'm quite bit confused when comes to prove this mathematically. How can i show step step values of i in terms of kth step. What is mathematical description of big-Oh of this loop ?

```
while i < n
    i = i^2 -i + 1
```

Comment: Could you come up with an answer if the loop were just ```i = i^2```? (It'd be useful for any answerer to know if building off that simpler case would be useful)

Comment: Which language is this? I use Python a lot, but that would also need a colon, plus the caret would be two asterisks instead.

Comment: The value of $i$ after the $k$-th iteration is between $(i-1)^{2^k}$ and $i^{2^k}$. Therefore, the loop stops between the smallest solutions of $2^{2^k}\geq n$ and $3^{2^k}\geq n$. Solve for $k$ in each $k\geq \log_2(\log_2(n))$ and $k\geq \log_2(\log_3(n))$. Recall that $\log_b(a)=\log_c(a)/\log_c(b)$ and that $\log_c(a/b)=\log_c(a)-\log_c(b)$. To conclude that both of those bounds are bounded by a constant multiple of $\log(\log(n))$.

Comment: @conditionalMethod that is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As the numbers grow, they approximately square at each step, so the growth is doubly  exponential.